# EF query to Oracle throwing "ORA-12704: character set mismatch"

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I'm trying to combine a few columns in EF from Oracle then do a `.Contains()` over the columns like this:

```
public IEnumerable<User> SearchUsers(string search)
{
    search = search.ToLower();

    return _securityUow.Users
            .Where(u => (u.FirstName.ToLower() + " " + u.LastName.ToLower() + " (" + u.NetId.ToLower() + ")").Contains(search))
            .OrderBy(u => u.LastName)
            .ThenBy(u => u.FirstName)
            .AsEnumerable();
}
```

However, I'm getting this exception:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException",
  "StackTrace": "   at SoftwareRegistration.WebUI.Controllers.Api.V1.UserContactController.Lookup(String search) in C:\LocalRepository\OnlineSupport\SoftwareRegistration\trunk\release\SoftwareRegistration\SoftwareRegistration.WebUI\Controllers\Api\V1\UserContactController.cs:line 40\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "ORA-12704: character set mismatch",
    "ExceptionType": "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException",
    "StackTrace": "   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)\r\n   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)\r\n   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)"
  }
}
```

The columns I'm querying are all of type VARCHAR2(128) in Oracle.

I'm also using this exact same code in another project and it works. The only difference is that for the project that works I'm using `Oracle.DataAccess` and for the one that doesn't work, I'm using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` (I am unable to use `Oracle.DataAccess` for this project). So I believe there is a bug/problem in the managed driver.

I'm open to solutions or workarounds.

Comment: What character set is your database using? Run `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'` to determine this.

Comment: i ran that, it says `WE8MSWIN1252`

Comment: Well, that's contrary to what I'd expected. `WE8MSWIN1252` is a single-byte character set, but IIRC .net uses Unicode internally so I'd expect that the database or driver should be able to convert from to/from the single-byte database character set to Unicode. I looked at the [OracleGlobalization class docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/OracleGlobalizationClass.htm#ODPNT3113) and it looks like none of the methods that allow setting the character set are available under the managed driver. Best of luck.

Comment: In deed, ODP.NET, Managed Driver is not NLS_LANG sensitive. It is only .NET locale sensitive, see [Globalization Support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/featGlobal.htm#ODPNT437). Maybe it helps when you try around with `ToLower(CultureInfo)`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ended up getting the author of this ([ODP.Net Managed Driver - ORA-12704: character set mismatch in generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693374/odp-net-managed-driver-ora-12704-character-set-mismatch-in-generated-code)) to update the question, he posted a workaround using an interceptor, I'll go a bit more detail here...

First, I decorated my DBContext to load a configuration. you can skip this and just add to your configuration if you have one:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
```

Create the config class:

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        this.AddInterceptor(new NVarcharInterceptor()); //add this line to existing config.
    }
}
```

Next, create the interceptor:

```
public class NVarcharInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (command != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.CommandText))
            command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("N''", "''");
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (command != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.CommandText))
            command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("N''", "''");
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (command != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.CommandText))
            command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("N''", "''");
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (command != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.CommandText))
            command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("N''", "''");
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (command != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.CommandText))
            command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("N''", "''");
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (command != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.CommandText))
            command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("N''", "''");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a word of caution: If your strings physically contain the string N'' then you are in for a surprise. Just my 2c. On top of that the approach would probably be better of it converted N' -> ' (instead of N'' -> '')

Comment: ` command.CommandText = Regex.Replace(command.CommandText, "(N)('[\\w\\d_]*')", "$2");`

Answer (score 3):

In these cases, it is better to do the concatenation of these queries manually depending on whether the columns are unicode or not, in some of these ways

```
return _securityUow.Users
    .Where(u => (u.FirstName.ToLower() + DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode(" ") + u.LastName.ToLower() + DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode(" (") + u.NetId.ToLower() + DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode(")")).Contains(search))
    ...

return _securityUow.Users
    .Where(u => (u.FirstName.ToLower() + DbFunctions.AsUnicode(" ") + u.LastName.ToLower() + DbFunctions.AsUnicode(" (") + u.NetId.ToLower() + DbFunctions.AsUnicode(")")).Contains(search))
    ...
```

Depending on the type of columns if they are NVarchar or Varchar (by default EF uses nvarchar unless .isUnicode is set in the property)

Answer (score 0):

I add a call to HasColumnType in my implementation of IEntityTypeConfiguration<>, works for me:

```
builder.Property(g => g.PropName).HasColumnName("ColName").HasColumnType("varchar2(40)")
```