# Entity Framework column concatenate in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

Im using EntityFramework 6.1 with Oracle, I need to write the query to concatenate two columns in where predict expression.

I used the below code:

```
/* t.Col1 : string , t.Col2: Enum */
db.Table1.Where(t => t.Col1 + " " + t.Col2 == "SomeValue");
```

But I get the **OracleException: ORA-12704: character set mismatch** error. I want to apply the condition before fetch the data from Database. So anyone has idea how can I handle this issue?

I already saw this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645274/ef-query-to-oracle-throwing-ora-12704-character-set-mismatch), but that solution doesn't work if one of the column be Enum.

Comment: if it is syntax error then it is not about Oracle or Sql. Your code seems ok. Can you tell us what compiler says ?

Comment: @ZaheerUlHassan that's link is solution for SQL Server, not Oracle

Comment: [EF query to Oracle throwing “ORA-12704: character set mismatch”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645274/ef-query-to-oracle-throwing-ora-12704-character-set-mismatch) check this.

Comment: Thanks guys it's working if all columns are string, but one of my column is Enum.