# Entity Framework cannot concat Enum column in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

Im using EntityFramework 6.1 with Oracle, I need to write the query to concatenate two columns in where predict expression.

I used the below code:

```
/* t.Col1 : string , t.Col2: Enum */
db.Table1.Where(t => t.Col1 + " " + t.Col2 == "SomeValue");
```

But I get the OracleException: ORA-12704: character set mismatch error. I want to apply the condition before fetch the data from Database. So anyone has idea how can I handle this issue?

I already saw this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645274/ef-query-to-oracle-throwing-ora-12704-character-set-mismatch), but that solution doesn't work if one of the column be Enum.

Comment: Could you possibly write the query by hand instead? Like this: `db.Table1.SqlQuery(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the commandtext and found try to convert empty char to NCLOB

```
THEN N'' ELSE TO_NCLOB
```

So I updated the @solidau answer with following solution:

```
command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("N''", "''").Replace("THEN '' ELSE TO_NCLOB", "THEN N'' ELSE TO_NCHAR");
```