# ORA-12704: character set mismatch with update statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework, oracle-manageddataaccess

I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client to make queries to oracle database, but having an issue in update query. I tried different workarounds like CAST with NVARCHAR2 and wrote DBInterceptor by following this Stack Overflow [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645274/ef-query-to-oracle-throwing-ora-12704-character-set-mismatch).
But none of them are working. I also have an Insert Statement with the same parameters and it works perfectly.

Update Statement:

```
string query = @"update APP_DB_TABLE set ""Tracking_NM""=:reportName, ""Start_DT""=:startDate, ""End_DT""=:endDate, ""Tracking_Developer_NM""=:devName, ""Tracking_Description_TXT""=:description," +
                @" ""RunBook_TXT""=:runbook, ""Parameter_TXT""=:params, ""Distribution_TXT""=:distributionList, ""OUTPUT_FILE_FILE_TXT""=:fileName," +
                @"""CategoryId""=:catId, ""TrackingStatusId""=:trackingStatusId, ""TrackingTypeId""=:trackingTypeId where ""Db_Table_ID""=:id";

            using (var conn = new OracleConnection(connection))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("id", data.Id);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("reportName", data.ReportName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("startDate", data.StartDate);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("endDate", data.EndDate);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("devName", data.DeveloperName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("description", data.ReportDescription);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("runbook", data.RunbookName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("params", data.ReportParameter);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("distributionList", data.DistributionList);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("fileName", data.OutputFileName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("catId", data.CategoryId);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("trackingStatusId", data.TrackingStatusId);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("trackingTypeId", data.TrackingTypeId);

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
```

Thanks.